# Why is it slower to grab image frame inside thread

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I'm putting together some Python code on the raspberry pi to grab image frames from the RPi camera using openCV. If the code is in a simple while loop it runs realtime without issue. However, I'd like to put the operation of the camera in a thread so the camera can run in the background and we grab frames when required. As a result I've done something equivalent to below as a simple camera class.

```py
import cv2
class cam:
    def __init__(self):        
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        #Create an empty image frame in case camera is not started before frame is used
        self.frame = np.zeros([cam_mode.width,cam_mode.height,3],dtype=np.uint8)
        
        #Objects for threading
        self.cam_thread = Thread(target=self.camera_thread,args=())
        self._lock = Lock()
        
    def start_camera(self):
        
        self.cam_thread.daemon = True
        self.cam_thread.start()
        
    def camera_thread(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            raise Exception("Camera is not running")
        while self.cont:
            #Lock so getting image is protected
            with self._lock:
                # get the image
                status, frame = self.cap.read()                
                if status:
                    self.frame = frame
                    
    def get_image(self):
        with self._lock:
            return self.frame.copy()
```

Then, accessed the camera and attempted to display images in a simple loop like so:

```py
my_cam = cam()
my_cam.start_camera()
while True:
      image = my_cam.get_image()
      cv2.imshow('',image)
      if(cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q")):
          break
```

In this example there are frequent and unpredictable delays and the images are displayed once or twice a second at best. I realise the introduction of multiple loops and the locks may introduce delays. I have looked into different models of threading to do this but this simple method seemed sufficient. Advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I understand it, the Python interpreter is single-threaded. Multi-threading in Python is a trick where the interpreter works on different threads in turn. So you don’t gain compute time by multi-threading, you just add overhead.

Comment: @CrisLuengo There should be a benefit to running multiple threads if there is I/O involved (which is the case here) as the GIL is released during read/write calls and also during Numpy calls.

Comment: @Mark Sure. But I don't think this I/O is slow enough. Reading from the camera is similar to reading from RAM, in my experience. Also, does OpenCV release the GIL?

Comment: Locking before camera.read() will lock nearly permanently, so your displaying cant read the image. Either push back frames in a queue or  1. read new frame to a second variable, then 2. lock and 3. replace your old frame by the new one.

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP's code locks the other thread out immediately before the `cam_get_image()` which is exactly when the GIL is about to be released which would ordinarily allow other threads to run.

Comment: Thanks all, I have implemented Cris Luengo's solution below and got it back up to real-time. I had some code detecting QR codes too and by putting this all outside of the lock get great performance. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following [Micka's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75770533/why-is-it-slower-to-grab-image-frame-inside-thread?noredirect=1#comment133663415_75770533), and with some additional changes to get your code to actually run, I came up with the following:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread, Lock


class cam:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # Create an empty image frame in case camera is not started before frame is used
        self.frame = np.zeros((256, 256), np.uint8)
        self.is_running = False

        #Objects for threading
        self.cam_thread = Thread(target=self.camera_thread,args=())
        self._lock = Lock()

    def start_camera(self):
        self.cam_thread.daemon = True
        self.cam_thread.start()
        self.is_running = True

    def camera_thread(self):
        while True:
            if self.is_running:
                status, frame = self.cap.read()
                if status:
                    # Lock so getting image is protected
                    with self._lock:
                        self.frame = frame

    def get_image(self):
        with self._lock:
            return self.frame.copy()


my_cam = cam()
my_cam.start_camera()
while True:
    image = my_cam.get_image()
    cv2.imshow('',image)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q")):
        break
```

Note that the main change here is calling `self.cap.read()` outside the lock, and locking only for the assignment `self.frame = frame`. (All the other changes are because of undefined variables and so on.)

In general, in a multi-threaded environment using locks, you want to have the code inside the lock to be as short as possible. Inside the lock you should only do the things that really require the lock. The longer it takes to run code inside the lock, the longer other threads will be waiting to acquire the lock. In this case, the time between releasing the lock and acquiring it again was too small, the other thread didn't often get a chance to acquire it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Apologies I'd left some code in from a 'settings' structure I've put together but wasn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score -2):

The way you are using the lock in the method below makes so that the its almost all the time locked in the image-grabbing thread  -  the only chance the other thread have to get the lock and retrieve the frame data  is if it attempts so when re-starting the while loop - in
practice, it depends on a race condition.

The way to fix it is, instead of trying to retrieve frames
"as fast as possible", to include a pause after each
frame is retrieved, and outside the lock.

In multi-threaded code, the standard way to make such
a pause is simply calling `time.sleep`

This should make your experiment better:

```
import time

FRAMERATE = 15
...

    def camera_thread(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            raise Exception("Camera is not running")
        while self.cont:
            #Lock so getting image is protected
            start_time = time.time()
            status, frame = self.cap.read() 
            with self._lock:            
                if status:
                    self.frame = frame
            ellapsed = time.time() - start_time
            time.sleep(max(0, 1/FRAMERATE - ellapsed))
...
```

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of running in two threads, or?

Comment: throwing a sleep in there, instead of moving the cap.read() out of the critical section, is, IMHO, a terrible kludge and should never ever be done, because the proper solution is just so simple and there's no reason not to do this properly

Comment: the sleep is needed nonetheless - unless one don't care for batteries or otherwise keep everything at 100% all the time.